# How to bind an object to a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the next task:

```
const person = {name: 'Arnold'};

function fn(salut, lastName) {
    console.log(salut, this.name, lastName);
}

const bindName = bind(fn, person, 'Mr');

bindName('Helgov');
```

I have to write a function that prints: `"Mr Arnold Helgov"`

My realization of this task is the next function:

```
function bind(fn, person, salute) {
    return (lastname) => {
        return fn(salute, lastname);
    }
}
```

But I have a problem here. My function prints only `"Mr  Helgov"` and the name `'Arnold'` is lost.  How to solve this problem (maybe by using `bind` or `apply` or `call`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to solve this problem (maybe by using `bind` or `apply` or `call`)?

Yes, you can use `call` or `bind` to make sure `this` gets to be equal to `person` during the call of `fn`.

With `call`:

```js
const person = {name: 'Arnold'};

function fn(salut, lastName) {
    console.log(salut, this.name, lastName);
}

const bindName = bind(fn, person, 'Mr');

bindName('Helgov');

function bind(fn, person, salute) {
    return (lastname) => {
        return fn.call(person, salute, lastname);
    }
}
```

Or, `bind`:

```js
const person = {name: 'Arnold'};

function fn(salut, lastName) {
    console.log(salut, this.name, lastName);
}

const bindName = bind(fn, person, 'Mr');

bindName('Helgov');

function bind(fn, person, salute) {
    return fn.bind(person, salute);
}
```